# Перетаскивание блоков как на сайте

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Доброго времени суток. Хотелось бы узнать как реализовать при помощи jquery перетаскиванием блоков как на сайте http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/ , что бы когда перетаскиваешь блок на тот где уже есть (какие то блоки), то они (блоки который уже имеется в этом главном блоке) сдвигались либо раздвигались. Или возможно кто-то делал что-то подобное. Про jquery Draggable знаю.
Либо подскажите как сформировать запрос для googl'a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

см. [Draggable+Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable). Причем на том сайте именно так и делают.

Comment: спасибо буду разбираться